# Why can't I embed images at exactly 10 reputation?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

I have an image that makes [Why do I see two sizes for storage space available?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20462/why-do-i-see-two-sizes-for-storage-space-available) immediately clear, but I cannot embed it inline. I'm given the error message "We're sorry, but as a spam prevention mechanism, new users aren't allowed to post images. Earn more than 10 reputation to post images.", but according to https://apple.stackexchange.com/privileges/user/9335, I should be good to go.

Do I need 11 reputation to embed images? If so, why does the list of privileges mislead users like that?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but try it now! :P

Comment: Aren't we clever!

Comment: I was wondering the same thing, because several people have this problem.

Answer (score 3):

It is a bit inconsistent, but we want it to be 11 in this case. Remember all users start out with 1 rep, so a single answer upvote +10 or two question upvotes +5 +5 will get you to 11 total.